# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^∞ P_n(x) - f(x) $, $P_n(x)$ Is the Maclaurin polynomial of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

We have $f(x)$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)$ exist for all $n > 0$, And let $P_n(x)$ be the Maclaurin polynomial of $f$ (of degree $n$).

Can I say for sure the following series converges for every $x$ In the radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series of $f$?

$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ (P_n(x) - f(x))$$

$P_n(x)$ ∼ $f(x)$ for growing values of $n$, So it seems true to me. But my intuition is not always true.

Re-writing the series to $$\sum_{n=1}^∞ (P_{n^2}(x) - f(x))  $$

Will change anything for a different $f$?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with definition and notations. First of all, a Taylor polynomial is defined near a point (its center). What is the center here? Is it $0$? Also, are you really considering the **sum** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(x)$ of Taylor polynomials?

Comment: @Taladris Yes you are right, It should be maclaurin  polynomial, Fixed. I am trying to understand If the maclaurin series converges to $f$ quick enough such that the given series will converge.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \left(P_n(x) - f(x)\right)  $ or $\left(\sum_{n=1}^∞ P_n(x)\right) - f(x)  $?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The first option.

Comment: Have you tried writing one of the [remainders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) in place of $P_n(x)-f(x)$? The integral form could be useful.

Comment: Study the link I gave. Substitute the integral form of the remainder, change the order of summation and integration and see what you get.

Comment: And the [Maclaurin polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) written at which point?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The Maclaurin polynomial is, by definition, the Taylor polynomial at the point $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If the Taylor series of $f$ about each point on the interval $(0,x)$ (or $(x,0)$) are absolutely and uniformly convergent then your sum is convergent and can be computed as follows. By the Taylor formula with integral remainder, we have
$$
f(x) = P_n (x) + \int_0^x {\frac{{f^{(n + 1)} (t)}}{{n!}}(x - t)^n dt} .
$$
On the other hand
$$
f'(x) = f'(t) + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{f^{(n + 1)} (t)}}{{n!}}(x - t)^n } 
$$ by the Taylor series expansion of $f'$ about $t$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(P_n (x) - f(x))} & =  - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_0^x {\frac{{f^{(n + 1)} (t)}}{{n!}}(x - t)^n dt} }  =  - \int_0^x {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{f^{(n + 1)} (t)}}{{n!}}(x - t)^n } dt}\\ & = \int_0^x {(f'(t) - f'(x))dt}  = f(x) - f(0) - f'(x)x
\\& =f(x)-P_0(x)-f'(x)x.
\end{align*}
This also yields
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {(P_n (x) - f(x))}  = -f'(x)x.
$$